# jQuery: How to find a li-tag with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<ul>` with many `<li>`.
My `<li>`'s have different id's: for example: `<li class="image" id=1>....</li>`
How can I find now this `<li>` with the id=1 ??
I tried this-->

```
var deleteImage =  $("ul").find( ".image" ).attr("id").val(1);
```

...but it doesnt work. Any idea? THANKS!!!

Comment: What about `$('#someId')`? Since the ID values should be unique throughout the document.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: HTML4 and below require non numeric IDs btw

Comment: If you use specific ids it's unnecessary to look search your ul's children, since ids are considered to be unique in the whole document. If that isn't the case, you might run into some weird behaviour with some browsers. So ids should always be used uniquely and the mehtod suggested by James Allardice works

Comment: You should learn how to use jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Its very easy to learn if you study it.

Comment: @Markai, that's not entirely true. If you wanted to address an id if it has a certain context, then you wouldn't use it alone. Imagine you have a `toto` id that can be put on variable elements (but only once per page), and that you want to style it ONLY if it's inside the `.foo` div then you'd have to use the selector `.foo #toto`.

Comment: @Antoine Combes that's true, but nevertheless should ids be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic JQuery/CSS selector:

```
var deleteImage =  $("ul").find( "#1.image" );
```

Answer (score 5):

ID's should **never** start with numbers. Change your id's to image1, image2, image3, ...
Then use:

```
$('#image1').functionToExecute();
```

Comment: Could you tell me why to never start with numbers?

Comment: @DennisAnderson look this answer for more details  http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/3963330

Answer (score 0):

The [id tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) is supposed to be unique within the HTML document.  So, assuming you've constructed the HTML appropriately, you should be able to select the `li` tag with just:

```
$('#1')
```